# Java 5 authorization header charset ISO-8859-2

Tags: java, web-services, http-headers, basic-authentication

I need your help. I have a rest WS that uses Authorization header. I have to use ISO-8859-2 charset.
When I test it on tomcat with java 6 (using jersey), in log everything looks fine.

Authorization header: Basic 12345:ruž

log:

```
2011-11-30 23:43:04,537 [http-8081-1] INFO  jersey.jaxb.model.TodoResource  - Username = 12345 Password = ruž
```

But when I test it on same tomcat wiht java 5 i get this:

```
2011-12-01 00:29:49,511 [http-8081-1] INFO  jersey.jaxb.model.TodoResource  - Username = 12345 Password = ru?…Â?
```

My java code:

```
...
auth = auth.substring("Basic ".length());
String[] values = new String(Base64.base64Decode(auth).getBytes("ISO-8859-2")).split(":");
String username = values[0];
String password = values[1];

logger.info("Username = " + username + " Password = "+ password);
```

Am I missing something or the problem is somewhere else.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're out of luck as anything outside of simple ASCII appears to be out of spec.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/703341/317667