# Why .htaccess and .htpasswd does not accept my log-in info

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

## My Question

Why .htaccess and .htpasswd does not accept my log-in info?

## My sources to learn what should I do

1. http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/
2. http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

## What I Did?

I took my full path info from `phpinfo()`

full path to my root: `/home/userid/public_html`

I put my .htpasswd into root folder (public_html) so full path to my .htpasswd: `/home/userid/public_html/.htpasswd`

my admin folder name that I want to protect via password: `adminfolder`

I put my `adminfolder` into root folder (public_html)

**Folder Structure**

```
public_html
---- .htaccess {permission: -rw-r--r--}
---- .htpasswd {permission: -rw-r--r--}
---- adminfolder {permission: drwxr-xr-x}
---- ---- .htaccess {permission: -rw-r--r--}
---- ---- other secret files {permission: -rw-r--r--}
```

### .htaccess code (the one in adminfolder)

```
AuthUserFile /home/userid/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthName "Log In"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

### .htpasswd code

note: This the encrypted version of my raw password.

```
admin:zv.sqVSz3W1nk
```

### .htaccess code (the one just in public_html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#always use www - redirect non-www to www permanently
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# hotlink protection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.p.ht [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$ - [NC,F,L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# File caching is another famous approach in optimizing website loading time
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# secure spesific files
<Files a_secret_file.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

#SEO friendly linking
...
...
```

### I checked

1. my fullpath info
2. username - raw and encrypted passwords
3. codings
4. all my files are prepared in notepad++ & encoded UTF-8 without BOM

### Lastly

I tried at chrome. I entered username + non-encrypted raw password. Chrome asked me to log-in again.
then I cleared all cache of IE. Again I entered username + non-encrypted password. IE also asked me to log-in again.

Can you please correct me? thanks, BR

Comment: hm... nicely structured question

Comment: did you tried to create another username and password?

Comment: try these: `test:clKAOxsMt8tC6` (test:test), `test:$apr1$EACwDAeN$mnZR16XpfBwIfyPfdQtaU1` (test:test)

Comment: @Akam  test:clKAOxsMt8tC6 and test:$apr1$EACwDAeN$mnZR16XpfBwIfyPfdQtaU1 both worked. So can you please offer me a trustable source to get my encrypted password. I used my 1st source to get a password but I think I should not use that site. Also please make your comment an answer for me to accept. lots of thanks. BR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is because your server might uses different algorithm to encrypt/decrypt the password, you can test different password combination from different algorithm in order to find-out the correct one.

Please see this site: http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html

It uses JavaScript for generating password, you can save the page and run it locally for security reasons.

Please check [Apache htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html)

Answer (score 2):

> note: This the encrypted version of my raw password.
>   admin:zv.sqVSz3W1nk

Unix http servers will interpret it as a crypt(3) hashed password,
but apache on windows/netware will interpret it as a plaintext password.
But I guess your server is a Unix one, so this is probably not the issue.

> all my files are prepared in notepad++ & encoded UTF-8 without BOM

Does your password contain some non-ascii characters, like french accents ?
Use only 7-bit ASCII characters if you want to keep things simple and cross-browser compatible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702629/utf-8-characters-mangled-in-http-basic-auth-username)