# UTF-8 characters mangled in HTTP Basic Auth username -> 5 years later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, utf-8, http-headers

I was reading the following topic [UTF-8 characters mangled in HTTP Basic Auth username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702629/utf-8-characters-mangled-in-http-basic-auth-username) because I'm experiencing the same problem in Rails.

Since the topic is from 2009, is there a solution after 5 years?

Kind regards

EDIT: If this is considered unorthodox to ask a question in this way -> I am very sorry.

Comment: Also alternatives that WORK are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution *proposal* in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpauth-basicauth-enc-02.html, but AFAIK it hasn't been implemented by user agents and servers yet.

Comment: The former proposal has recently become [RFC 7617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617). Of course, it will still take time before it will be implemented in most software.